# can a Windows OS have different default Time To Live values (TTL) depending on protocol?

Tags: tcp

I send two requests to a remote host:

- request1 (ICMP request): ping **IP_adresse**
- request2 (TCP request):  hping3 -S -p open_port **IP_adresse**

I received two responses that show different TTL:

- response1: 64 bytes from **IP_adresse**: icmp_req=1 ttl=**121** time=78.3 ms
- response2: len=56 ip=**IP_adresse** ttl=**111** DF id=5156 flags=SA seq=0 win=1460 rtt=1729.1 ms

According to this [link](http://www.binbert.com/blog/2009/12/default-time-to-live-ttl-values/), recent Windows OS releases have the same default TTL=128 for all protocoles

Why the TTL received in the two responses TCP & ICMP is different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In default configuration TTL for all communication is the same.

What you're experiencing is either:

1. There's a different path taken by each of those protocols in the network - due to things like traffic engineering, different routing policies or whatever is between you and the destination host.
2. There's a box in the middle (like firewall or something similar) that's modifying the TTL field because either that's a policy (and for one protocol it's in place, for the other it's not) or it's doing something in addition to just processing the packet from one side to the other.